# Exact sequence and Vector Bundles on $\mathbb{P}^{n}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, exact-sequence

In the article : On globally generated vector bundles on projective spaces, the authors prove the following lemma

> **Lemma 4**. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a generated vector bundle on $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ and $\mathcal{E}^{*}$ denote its dual bundle. If $h^{1}(\mathcal{E}^{*}) = s$ then there exists a globally generated vector bundle $\mathcal{G}$ such that $h^{0}(\mathcal{G}^{*}) = h^{0}(\mathcal{E}^{*}) $, $h^{1}(\mathcal{G}^{*}) = 0$ and an exact sequence $0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}^{\oplus s} \longrightarrow \mathcal{G} \longrightarrow \mathcal{E} \longrightarrow 0 $.

In proof of this result, the authors state that the exact sequence above can be easily obtained by induction on s, having in mind that $\text{Ext}^{1}(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}) \simeq H^{1}(\mathcal{E}^{*})$.  Is this really easy to obtain? Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Using $\operatorname{Ext}^1(E,O)=H^1(E^*)$, one gets an exact sequence, $0\to O\to H\to E\to 0$, by choosing a non-zero element in $H^1(E^*)$. Now, check that $H^1(H^*)$ has dimension $s-1$ and thus by induction, you have $0\to O^{s-1}\to G\to H\to 0$. Take the pull back of $O\to H$ to get what you want.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much, @Mohan.